# How to print the first letter of each word in a sentence?

Tags: python

I got this question in a quiz last week, a lot of people got it wrong, so I am pretty sure it will be on our midterm:

> Write a function that takes as a parameter a list of strings and
>   returns a list containing the first letter of each of the strings.
>   That is, if the input parameter is ["Daniel","Nashyl","Orla",
>   "Simone","Zakaria"], your function should return ['D', 'N', 'O', 'S',
>   'Z']. The file you submit should include a main() function that
>   demonstrates that your function works.

I know you can use this `[#:#]` to print any letters of a word or sentence.

```
>>> `x = "Java, Python, Ruby"`
>>> `x[:13]`
'Java, Python,'
>>> `x[:-1]`
'Java, Python, Rub'
>>> `x[:1]`
'J'
```

But I get confused when it comes to printing the first letter of a bunch of words. I also think that the ".split" function is needed here. I am using python 3.3.3

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_letters(lst):
    return [s[:1] for s in lst]

def main():
    lst = ["Daniel","Nashyl","Orla", "Simone","Zakaria"]
    assert first_letters(lst) == ['D', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'Z']

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

`str.split` takes a string and breaks it into a list of strings. Your input is already a list of strings, therefore you do not need .split.

`"mystring"[:1]` gets the first character of the string (or `""` if the string is `""` to begin with). Apply this to each string in the input list, and return the result.

Comment: Code without explanation isn't very useful. Consider: Do you want to give him/her a fish, or teach him/her to fish?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, you have a point; I have difficulty believing people can muck up something so basic, but the evidence keeps piling up :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You'll definitely want to read about them! Here's a minimal example that does what you're looking for:

```
>>> L =  ["Daniel","Nashyl","Orla", "Simone","Zakaria"]
>>> [item[0] for item in L]
['D', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'Z']
```

This loops through each name in your list and creates a new list from the first letter of each item in the original list. For example, `"Daniel"[0] == 'D'`. No `.split` is needed.

Comment: `item[:1]` is a bit safer than `item[0]` - if you ever apply it against an empty string, `""[:1]` will return an empty string where `""[0]` throws an IndexError.

Comment: Hey i tried to use this form as is the one i understand the most, but i didn't get the results i wanted. by the way im trying to use the "input" function.

Comment: That was meant as an illustration of how to get the first letter of each item in the list, not a complete answer to your test question. Try pasting each line into the Python interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are cool, and you should learn to use them indeed, but let me explain a bit what's going on here, since in your question you said you're confused how to do it with a bunch of strings.

So, you have a list of strings. Lists are an *iterable collection*, which means we can iterate through it using, for example, a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
words = ["Daniel","Nashyl","Orla", "Simone","Zakaria"]
for word in words:
   print word[:1]
```

I'm sure you were taught about loops like this in class. Now, instead of printing the first letter, let's construct a new list that contains those letters:

```
result = []
for word in words:
   result.append(word[:1])
```

Here I created a new list, then for every word, I [append](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)ed the starting letter of that word to the new list. A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) does the same thing, with a more obscure syntax, more elegance, and a bit more efficiency:

```
result = [word[:1] for word in words]
```

This is the gist of it.